# how to show table records in good format in ubuntu terminal

Tags: sql, database, ubuntu, terminal, cassandra

When I execute query in terminal "Select * from post_log;", the output is messed up and not displaying in well format. I found a couple of solutions such as use \G, "Select * from post_log \G;", but it give me error   "Invalid syntax at line 1, char 51 select * from post_log \G;"
How can I display table records in well format in ubuntu terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use cqlsh -e option to export the query rsult to output.txt or install devcenter java client app